# Question on decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that if $f(x)$ , $x \in \Re$ is decreasing and there exists $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)<x_0$ then there exists $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)\ge x_1$?

Comment: what is the domain of $f$? All of $\Re$?

Comment: Here is a hint: Suppose $f(x_0) = y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then what range of values can $f(x)$ for $x < x_0$ lie in?

Comment: yes the domain is $\Re$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given that the domain of $f$ is $\Re$, it makes sense to calculate $f(x_1)$ where $x_1 = f(x_0)$. Since $f$ is decreasing and $f(x_0) = x_1 < x_0$ we have $f(x_1) \ge f(x_0) = x_1$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $x_1=x_0-d$ for some $d>0$, then
$$f(x_1)-x_1 \geq f(x_0) -x_0 +d$$
by choosing $d$ large enough, we see that the right hand side is positive. Thus we conclude the existence of $x_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more analytical answer.

It's clear that if $x\gt x_o$ , then $f(x) \lt f(x_o) \lt x_o \lt x$ .

So if such an $x_1$ may exist , then $x_1\lt x$ .

We prove by contradiction the existence of $x_1$

If possible, let $f(x) \lt x 
,  \forall    x \lt x_o$

Let $g(x) =x-f(x) , x\lt x_o$

Clearly, $g(x) \gt 0$

Claim : $ g(x)$   is increasing function.

Proof :-

Let $a\lt b \lt x_o$

Since $f$ is decreasing

$f(a) \gt f(b)$

$\Rightarrow  a-f(a) \lt b-f(b)$

$\Rightarrow g(a) \lt g(b)$

So the claim is proved.

Thus the set $\{ g(x) | x\lt x_o\}$
is bounded below with the greatest lower bound zero.

So $\exists  a\lt x_o $ such that $ 
g(a)=0$ thus contradicting our assumption .